# Make a laravel query to search data which are between two time

Tags: php, laravel

There are two case for the query.

1. Two time in the same day.
2. The second time in the next day.

[image]

I am using php to check now as the following code, but how can I do it in Laravel query? Is it the better way to handle this case?

```php
if($period->order_start > $period->order_end) {
            if($period->order_start >= $current && $period->order_end <= $current) return false;
        } else {
            if($period->order_start >= $current || $period->order_end <= $current) return false;
        }
```

### New update!

I got data correctly by using the following sql. How I can use it in Laravel query clearly? Thanks!

```sql
SELECT * FROM `period`
WHERE IF(order_start < order_end, order_start > now() AND order_end < now(), order_start > now() OR order_end < now())
```

Comment: There is no such thing in your database to identify the order of the next day, Add order date in your system so that you can easily identify the order of next day.

Comment: please put your table structure.. in that you have order id or order date to identify order for day

Comment: use `whereTime` like this : `Model::whereTime(order_start,'>=',now())->whereTime('order_end','<=',now())->get()`

Comment: @AnkurTiwari If `order_start` > `order _end`, it means the `order_end` is on next day. Can I do that?

Comment: @Ivan Thanks. But this query only available when the same day. Is any solution that can check when `order_start > order _end` (Next day)

Comment: @Angus What happens when the order of yesterday having `order_start 21:00:00` and `order_end 18:00:00`?

Comment: @AnkurTiwari This table is the periods list. I need to check which periods is including the specific time. For example, if the time is 12:40:00, the output only have 'lunch'.

Comment: @Angus can you share your table structure here?

Comment: @Angus As I can see you only have `order_start` and `order_end` in time, NOT included date so how to know today or next day. I suggest you using `Timestamp` column type and use Laravel `whereBetween`

Answer (score 0):

If possible convert the 'order_start' and 'order_end' as DateTime in your database so that you can easily compare the time in both of the cases. It can prevent the bug if the order_start and order_end are in same time.

Otherwise you can check.

```html
if(order_time < order_end)
{
    this is for current date;
}else
{
    this is for another date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your Model name is FoodType and you just want to check either your foodtype is either Lunch or Dinner based on current date time than you can check it like below

```
$currentdatetime = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
$foodtype = FoodType::whereRaw('? between order_start and order_end', $currentdatetime)
    ->first();
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Thanks. But the second case is if `order_end < order_start`, how can I add  condition into the query?

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
$currentTime = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($timeNow);

$query->where(function ($query) use ($currentTime) {

        $query->where('order_start', '>', $currentTime)
        ->where('order_end', '<=', $currentTime);

    })->orWhere(function ($query) use ($currentTime) {

        $query->where('order_start', '>', $currentTime)
        ->orWhere('order_end', '<=', $currentTime)

    });
```

I hope it will helps.